# Add 1 backslash as first character in string

Tags: python, scapy, netfilter

I'm actually crafting TCP packet and I need to script that.

*[EDIT]
Example: I have a packet: \x00\x10\7ff\ff
I would like to add at the end: \xb3 without hard coding it.
Just do something like: b = "\" + hex(179)[1:]*

I would like a string like: 
a = "\xb3"

My crafted packet is working when I hard code it but I would like to do something like:
b = "\" + hex(179)[1:]
But I can't write only 1 backslash...

Before answer me: Just add "\ \". It's not working because when I print "a" python display an unknown character (what I need) and if I print b = "\ \" + hex(179)[1:], it display "\xb3" but it's not what I need to craft my packet.

Thanks you for your help

Comment: `a = "\xb3"` does not define a string with 4 characters. You don't want to be adding backslashes manually to anything.

Comment: `\x...` is an escape sequence. You can't separate it into chunks and expect Python to work out what to do when you stitch it back together (is that a literal x or ...).

Comment: When I do "type(a), it display <str>. And yes, I want to add backslash manually....

Comment: No, you don't, if the goal is to create a TCP packet, because the backslash is not actually part of the *value*; that's just how Python displays an otherwise unprintable character.

Comment: Compare `len("\\" + hex(179)[1:])` and `len("\xb3")`.

Answer (score 2):

You probably want the `struct` module. `pack` returns the byte string that you are looking for. In particular, the `B` format takes a single integer between 0 and 255 and packs it as a single byte in the output, rather than a string that contains a string representation of such a byte.

```
>>> struct.pack('B', 179)
b'\xb3'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, it's exactly what I was looking for!